# forfiles with UNC path

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I am trying to use forfiles to delete files that are older than 7 days. The files are in a UNC path. Below is the script that I am using.

```
Forfiles -p \\devexpress\C$\FULL\ -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

But I get an error mentioning that UNC paths (`\\machine\share`) are not supported.

There appears to be workarounds available but cannot get a clear answer googling.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error I get when trying to reproduce the problem says that the problem is not with FORFILES not suporting UNC Path, but with CMD not being able to start with an UNC path as default directory.  In case that this is also your problem, there are three approaches to solve it.

1. you might assign the UNC path to a disk letter, via `NET USE`

   ```
   NET USE V: \\devexpress\C$
   Forfiles -p V:\FULL\ -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"
   ```
2. You may bypass `CMD` and directly use some ERASEFILE executable utility directly in the -C option of the `FORFILES`
3. You may bypass `FORFILES` and use `FOR` command with some date checking logic instead. See my answer to this Stack overflow question [How can I check the time stamp creation of a file in a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840156/how-can-i-check-the-time-stamp-creation-of-a-file-in-a-windows-batch-script)

Answer (score 75):

Enhanced solution to the PA's first answer is:

```
PushD "\\devexpress\C$\FULL\" &&(
    forfiles -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /q @path" 
     ) & PopD
```

The PushD command maps the UNC path to free drive letter automatically, so this is portable approach.
Found in http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=24241.

Comment: it is also worth noting that the `popd` command will unmap the drive afterward

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
PushD "\\DS\Tajana\Arhiva\Arhive po danima" &&("forfiles.exe" /s /m "*.*" /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @path") & PopD
```

although I get a message about the error in cmd window  "not supporting UNC Path" but it still deletes files older than 7 days