# forfiles not working in scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have created a batch file with the following line:

```
forfiles /p L:\percepsrvr\SQL /s /m *.bak /d -4 /c "cmd /c del /q @PATH "
```

This deletes any files older than 3 days and works when I run the batch file.

However, when I try to run this batch file as part of a scheduled task the line of code fails to execute.  I think it might be because of the mapped network drive (L:) but don't know for sure.

I have the scheduled task running as myself to make sure it has the same permissions as when I run it manually.  The scheduled task is running on a Win2008r2 server box and L:\ is on a Win2003 SP2 server box.

Anyone know what might be keeping this from working properly or how to debug a scheduled task?

TIA
Brian

Comment: Have you tried running this without using the map - using \\Servername\ShareFolder\ ?

Comment: UNC paths are not supported in forfiles.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you! You might want to try the solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503491/forfiles-with-unc-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this post I found a solution as follows:

```
ROBOCOPY "D:\Backup Data\percepsrvr\SQL" "\\belgrade\v$\percepsrvr\SQL"

ROBOCOPY "\\belgrade\v$\percepsrvr\SQL" "\\belgrade\v$\percepsrvr\SQL\Old" *.* /move /minage:10
DEL "\\belgrade\v$\percepsrvr\SQL\Old\*.*" /Q
```

Basically, move the files to delete to another directory and then delete that directory (which can be done with RoboCopy).