# Batch runs manually but not in scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I don't generally write `batches`, but I currently have a `batch` that uses `forfiles` to copy my FLVs from one folder to another. When I run the batch manually it works every time, but from a scheduled task, it throws a `(0x1)` error.

```
forfiles -p "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Media Server 4.5\applications\name\streams" -m *.flv -s -d -1 -c "cmd /c copy @file ^0x22C:\Program^ Files\Adobe\Flash^ Media^ Server^ 4.5\applications\name\output\"
```

Not sure what syntax the scheduled task doesn't like.

**Update**

Under my scheduled task, Actions I have the following:

```
Program/script:  name.bat
Start in (optional): \\servername\file\to\batch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When my `Start in (optional):` path was a UNC path, it wouldn't work. So I moved my batch on the server and everything worked correctly.

[UNC in Windows Batch Files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#UNC_in_Windows_Batch_Files)

[forfiles with UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503491/forfiles-with-unc-path)

Comment: That is really a **workaround** - **NOT** the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 10):

Hi might be this is helpful,
I also face the same issue.
Just set the startin path like:

[image]

Here start in path is the path of batch file:
like you have enter in program script:
"E:\program related files\demo.bat"
then in startin just pass:
E:\program related files & done!

Answer (score 1):

On Server 2008 R2 when running the batch file under domain user credentials, with confirmed "log on as a batch job" security in the Local Security Policy>Local Settings>User Rights Assignment,
even then my batch (copying a log file to a network share) would not run as scheduled task, until I selected in tab *General* the option "**Run with highest privileges**" (default NOT checked!)
The option *Run whether user is logged on or not* was also selected, with radio-button, but I guess this is quite standard, when selecting to run the task using a domain user account.

For the tab Actions : specifying the entire batch file name including its path, directly in "Program/script:" works fine (with Server 2008 R2)
Using double quotes inside the batch file causes no problems.

Answer (score 1):

See the screen shot bellow.
You need to change the user to system[image]

Comment: I must say, windows schedule tasks aren't my favorite. if you can I recommend to run  a small linux machine and handles it with cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for such problems is permissions: scheduled tasks does **NOT** always run with **your** user credentials. If you want scheduled task to run as **you** you will have to set it up as **you** or alternative user.

Besides that I hope that your line of code is a **content** of your batch file, you are not trying to run this command directly. Or are you?

P.S. What are these `^0x22` and `^` doing in your code?

Comment: I have the scheduled task running under a user that has permission. [^0x22](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html), if I don't have ^0x22 in my destination path the batch doesn't work.

Comment: Just to eliminate that as a potential problems: try to specify complete path to `cmd` i.e. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` and simple (with no spaces) target path for copy. If that does not help than I have no idea what else it may be. Post your solution when you find one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but just wanted to share some info.

The *(0x01)* error code can also refer to resources that are not found. Therefore:

- all files/folders referd from within the batch file should be accessible to the user which account is being used to run that scheduled task;
- pay attention when using network locations in combination with "Run whether user is logged on or not" option;
- the above-mentioned option can be tricky to use because some resources may be available only after log on.

Answer (score 0):

For .bat files to run inside your scheduled task, you need to specify your .bat file path inside the start option - despite the fact that your .bat file is at the same directory as your .exe. Also, I flagged it to run with highest privilege.  After I have done those two things, the task suddenly takes off without any problem!

[image: windows schedule task picture]