# How to run a react front end app from a .bat file

Tags: reactjs, batch-file, server

I am deploying a react front end app to interact with an API that is controlling a 15 X 3 Video Wall (This is an array of displays). The app will be running on a NUC (Windows 10) in a local, isolated network in the localhost. I want to set either a scheduled task when windows startup (in case of power failure) or create a service that runs my npm start. I have tried some variants but none work. How can I do this?

I have tried qckwinsvc which runs a .js file but I can not figure out how to actually tell to run the start script in my package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about a cronjob that check if the server is running every certain amount of time, if the server is not running you can use `shelljs` to execute and start you localhost server or `npm start`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Comment: mmmm... I like your suggestion more than my solution which will work only on windows startup. Thanks, I will test out but at least I saved the day for now with the windows scheduler. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got it sorted out.

create a .bat file inside your /src folder with this

start cmd.exe /k "call npm start"
pause

and then set the schedule on startup with these instructions.

[Batch File runs manually but not in task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420003/batch-file-runs-manually-but-not-in-task-scheduler)