# Java's jps cannot find task when run by task scheduler

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

**Setup:**

I have 2 batch files:

1. runs java application (java -jar xyz.jar)
2. search for given application and kills it: (for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('jps -m ^| find "xyza"') do ( taskkill /F /PID %%i ))

When I run 1. and execute 2. from cmd everything works fine.

**Problem:** When I run 1. from the task scheduler and execute 2. the jps won't find the application (jps does not find the application)

I have multiple java applications so I cant do "taskkill java.exe" (as I need to kill just this one)

**How to run *1.* so jps can "see it"?**

I have found the same problem posted 7 years ago, however, the presented solutions do not work for me: [Batch File runs manually but not in task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420003/batch-file-runs-manually-but-not-in-task-scheduler?newreg=1927b03c7c2547098bee0c9b3b469e85)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Unfortunately, I couldn't solve it with the task scheduler. I ended up moving away from the task scheduler and using another tool to schedule tasks.