# security error when trying to run a powershell script from Task scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I started by creating a new basic task in task scheduler:  program/scripts: powershell.exe

The file path was put in `“add arguments”: -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass D:\DATA-MEDION\soft_ontwikkeling\powershell\zendRecentPGP16.ps1` .
Before doing this I opened a powershell window as admin and have put the `executionPolicy` to `unrestricted`.

I still get the `“cannot be loaded ...”` security error when running the scheduled task. (Ultrashort powershell window opening and closing).

I ran the same script in a powerscript command box and in powershell ISE and it was OK. 
Any idea's?

Comment: Have you made sure that the `Run only when user is logged on` option is off? And is the `Run with highest priveleges` is checked?

Comment: Thanks TechGuy. I did this and the task history is confirming now that it ran but, although not 'hidden', I did not see the blue powershell window anymore and the tasks scripted in the powershell ps1 are not executed. As said, they are executed when I run the ame ps1 in command box and in ISE.

Comment: This question might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259951/powershell-script-does-not-run-via-scheduled-tasks and this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513264/batch-runs-manually-but-not-in-scheduled-task