# UNC paths (\\machine\share) are not supported

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, unc

I have been struggling with the following error for 2 days now `ERROR: UNC paths (\\machine\share) are not supported.` and have finally come across something that got plenty of up-votes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503491/forfiles-with-unc-path).

The poster mentions using `pushd` and `popd` to map to a free drive letter. But I have absolutely no Idea how to do this. and quite frankly, i'm afraid I mess something up :(

How would I implement this `pushd` & `popd` into my SQL code:

```
    DECLARE @N AS VARCHAR(2) -- days for retention
    DECLARE @path AS VARCHAR(128) -- the path for deletion
    DECLARE @cmd AS VARCHAR(512) -- the actual command
  
    SET @N = '7' -- change the days here (Deleting files which are older that @N days)
    SET @path = '\\TOMANYMS\c$\JohnDoe\91\TEST\serverapps\export' -- Path of the files you would like to check
    SET @cmd = 'FORFILES /P "' + @path + '" /S /M export_status.* /D -' + @N + ' /C "cmd /c del @PATH"' --Deletes on the export_status files older than 7 days.

    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

I assume I would need to put it in the line where I am setting `@cmd`.

Any help would be great,

Thanks so much

Comment: If I understand correctly you'd like to search a path and its subfolders for a certain file mask and delete if the file is older than 7 days? I could suggest a number of other ways to do this from SQL which don't require `FORFILES ` if you wish.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - That would be absolutely great! I thought this was the only way to really go about it :)

Comment: For example this page shows the ROBOCOPY method of doing this and I'm guesing ROBOCOPY doesn't mind UNC's... any reason you don't want to use that method? http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-delolder.html

Comment: You could also write a T-SQL cursor to loop through the files and delete as required

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the DOS command using the & operator like this:

```
set @cmd = 'pushd '+ @path+  ' & FORFILES /P \ /S /M export_status.* /D -' + @N + ' /C "cmd /c del @PATH"'+' & popd'
```

Comment: Thanks Jaco, I tried this out and still get some errors. I have just decided to go the `SSIS` route. Thank you for your help.