# Batch delete files on FTP older than x days

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

Found several solutions for local, but need one for FTP action:

I have a daily batch script to backup MySQL databases locally, however I also ftp them to a backup server.

Locally, I am using `forfiles` to delete files older than 14 days:

```
forfiles -p "C:\whatever" -s -m *.* -d 14 -c "cmd /c del @path"`
```

The same I would like to do on FTP, once the newest backup files are dumped into FTP server running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

How do I extend my batch file to do this action?

```
cd\[path to directory where files are saved] 
echo off
echo user [ftp username]>ftpup.dat
echo [ftp password]>>ftpup.dat
echo binary>>ftpup.dat
echo put [FullBackup.%backupdate%.zip]>>ftpup.dat
echo quit>>ftpup.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpup.dat [myserver.com]
del ftpup.dat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. capture the list of files you are interested in

   ```
   echo user [ftp username]>ftpdir.txt
   echo [ftp password]>>ftpdir.txt
   echo dir . ftplist.txt >>ftpdir.txt
   echo quit>>ftpdir.txt
   ftp -n -s:ftpdir.txt [myserver.com]
   ```
2. prepare the ftp delete script

   ```
   echo user [ftp username]>ftpdel.txt
   echo [ftp password]>>ftpdel.txt
   ```
3. process the list

   ```
    for /f "tokens=6,7,8,*" %%a in (ftplist.txt) do (
       echo %%d
    )
   ```
4. inside the loop, extract the file date.

   ```
   echo %%c %%a %%b - %%d
   ```

   And transform the month name into a number

   ```
   call :month %%a
   ```

   you may use the routine found in http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php
5. inside the loop, transform the date into a number of days since today

   ```
   call :days %%c %month% %%b
   ```

   this is a call to a routine that computes the days using the Fliegel-Van Flandern algorithm. See this SO question for details and implementation [How can I check the time stamp creation of a file in a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840156/how-can-i-check-the-time-stamp-creation-of-a-file-in-a-windows-batch-script)
6. and finally, inside the loop, compare the resulting number, if it is bigger than, say, 14, add the file to the files to delete ftp script

   ```
   IF !days! GEQ 14 echo DEL %%d >>ftpdel.txt
   ```
7. finish the ftp del script and execute it

   ```
   echo quit>>ftpdel.txt
   ftp -n -s:ftpdel.txt [myserver.com]
   ```

Answer (score 5):

It's cumbersome to implement with the built-in `ftp.exe`, as the very good [answer by @PA.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9626618/850848#9683994) shows.

You better use some more powerful scriptable 3rd party FTP client.

---

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), it's as trivial as:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=delete.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "rm /remote/path/*<14D" ^
    "exit"
```

See [file masks with time constraints](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: This is perfect for deleting old stuff without having to list them prior